# the alignment of char array is 4 byte?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, alignment, eabi

tools & platform: gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9, cotrex-M4F

when I declaration `const char` variables, the alignment of memory map seems likes difference between `const char bb` and `const char bb[1]`

**case A:**

```
const char aa = 0;
const char bb = 1;
const char cc = 2;

.rodata.aa
                0x0005dbb0        0x1 ./source/main.o
                0x0005dbb0                aa
.rodata.bb
                0x0005dbb1        0x1 ./source/main.o
                0x0005dbb1                bb
.rodata.cc
                0x0005dbb2        0x1 ./source/main.o
                0x0005dbb2                cc
```

**case B:**

```
const char aa = 0;
const char bb[1] = {1};
const char cc = 2;

.rodata.aa
                0x0005dbb0        0x1 ./source/main.o
                0x0005dbb0                aa
*fill*          0x0005dbb1        0x3
.rodata.bb
                0x0005dbb4        0x1 ./source/main.o //why align to 4 byte here?
                0x0005dbb4                bb
.rodata.cc
                0x0005dbb5        0x1 ./source/main.o
                0x0005dbb5                cc
```

**case C:**

```
const char aa = 0;
const char bb[1] __attribute__ ((aligned (1))) = {1};
const char cc = 2;

.rodata.aa
                0x0005dbb0        0x1 ./source/main.o
                0x0005dbb0                aa
.rodata.bb
                0x0005dbb1        0x1 ./source/main.o
                0x0005dbb1                bb
.rodata.cc
                0x0005dbb2        0x1 ./source/main.o
                0x0005dbb2                cc
```

why, `const char bb[1]` align to 4 byte ?

how to make `const char bb[1]` align to 1 byte, like `const char bb`

Comment: You can use the `#pragma pack n` option to control that. But use with care!

Comment: Why bother? I'd trust the compiler here to and in this scenario I see little benefit in forcing the data to be non-aligned. I could see the compiler possibly to apply this alignment to char arrays in general without optimizations to really small arrays to optimize accessing elements by index... Your compiler should provide options that allow you to optimize the binary size, if you bothered about that...

Comment: It is more efficient to load a 'char []' in multiple characters to 32bit registers.  You can compare four characters at a time.  Loading/storing to aligned address is more cache efficient.  Different compiler options such as '-Os', etc could also pack the characters.  Making them static could also increase the probability.  As above, there are competing goals of efficiency and RAM use.

Comment: Hi, @artlessnoise, you are right, `-Os` align `bb[1]` to 1 byte. Other options `-O0 -O1 -O2 -O3` negative. Do you know the key word of options in `-Os` make the difference.

Comment: @fabian, because I have a python script to preprocess variables, and I want to do the same rule to process variable or array, using trans a variable to `variable[1]`.